# Why the significance of other variables change when I put the GDP in levels or growth rate?

Tags: regression, eviews

I'm doing a linear regression with data from 1980 to 2018.
Can you help me understanding why when I use the GDP in levels most of the others variables are significant and when I use the GDP growth rate they are not significant?
I used the growth rate for all the other variables.
This is the output I have with GDP in levels:[image]

And this is the output I have with gdp growth rate:[image]

Is there a way to justify I'm using in a regression a variable in levels and not its growth rate?
Thank you for your help.